# How I can clear CustomValidator ErrorMessage through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How I can clear a `CustomValidator` `ErrorMessage` text value through a JavaScript function. Please provide me the solution.

Thanks All.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you would like to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

The Text value of the validator is what gets displayed where the validator is rendered. The ErrorMessage value is what gets displayed in the ValidationSummary, if the page has one.

To clear the values, use the following javascript after the page has loaded.

To clear the Text value, you'll need to clear the inner contents of the validator's span that gets rendered.

```
document.getElementById('MyValidator').innerHTML = '';
```

With javascript, .net creates a variable for each validator and sets the properties. So, just set the errormessage property after this point (usually on load of the page).

```
MyValidator.errormessage = '';
```